# Imprimir frase con distintos datos

Tags: python, string, selenium-webdriver, concatenación

soy nuevo y estoy estancado con mi código. Especialmente para imprimir una frase con distintos datos obtenidos previamente a traves de la función *len()*

Función madre con la que obtengo el números de elementos con el que trabajaré. Con esto obtengo un numero x que usaré mas adelante.

```
#FUNCION QUE INDICA EN NUMERO LOS CASOS CRM
casos_pendientes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="entity_control-pcf_grid_control_container"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div')
n = len(casos_pendientes)
print("Casos CRM: " + str(n))
```

El siguiente código imprime el texto que quiero expresar.

```
#MUESTRA EL LISTADO DE CASOS
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    fila_caso = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div['+str(x)+']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/span').text
    dato_caso = fila_caso[26:]
    print(dato_caso)

RESULTADO DATO CASO = 
Desconoce sobrancia
Desconoce entrega
Recuperación de pieza
Recuperación de pieza
Recuperación de pieza
Recuperación de pieza
```

Este código obtiene números que se acompañará con ***dato_caso***

```
for y in range(1, n + 1):
    fila_ot = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="entity_control-pcf_grid_control_container"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div['+str(y)+']/div[6]').text
    print(fila_ot)

RESULTADO FILA OT =
712540085843
712537482576
95502476963
521601092364
81703119643
520403104060
```

Finalmente este el el código que no he logrado obtener lo requerido

```
for k in range(1, n + 1):
    oracion = "Actividad: {} OT: {}".format(dato_caso, fila_ot)
    print(oracion)
    #print("Actividad: " + dato_caso + " OT: " + fila_ot)

RESULTADO ORACION =
Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060
Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060
Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060
Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060
Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060
Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060

RESULTADO ESPERADO = 
    Actividad:  Desconoce sobrancia   OT: 712540085843
    Actividad:  Desconoce entrega     OT: 712537482576
    Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 95502476963
    Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 521601092364
    Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 81703119643
    Actividad:  Recuperación de pieza OT: 520403104060
```

Ya finalizando lo que busco obtener es asociar los eventos correspondientes a cada resultado obtenido según su naturaleza.
En la siguiente imágen se ilustra la asociación que busco poder expresar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Buen día, el problema es que tanto `dato_caso` como `fila_ot` están siendo asignadas dentro del ciclo `for`, es decir, únicamente guardas lo último que recibe después de iterar. Lo que necesitas es crear una lista y adentro del `for` adjuntar los valores con `append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Tal como puse en el comentario, lo que sucede es que en tu `for` estás únicamente asignando el valor actual de la iteración en tus variables, por lo que en el ciclo siguiente el valor se sobreescribe y al finalizar el ciclo `for` la variable tendrá únicamente el último valor asignado

Lo que necesitas es crear una lista con todos los valores que obtienes, por ejemplo para `dato_caso`

```
#Lista de dato_caso
lista_dato_caso = []
#MUESTRA EL LISTADO DE CASOS
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    fila_caso = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div['+str(x)+']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/span').text
    dato_caso = fila_caso[26:]
    print(dato_caso)
    lista_dato_caso.append(dato_caso)
```

Lo mismo para `fila_ot`:

```
#Lista de fila_ot
lista_fila_ot = []
for y in range(1, n + 1):
    fila_ot = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="entity_control-pcf_grid_control_container"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div['+str(y)+']/div[6]').text
    print(fila_ot)
    lista_fila_ot.append(fila_ot)
```

Y luego utilizas esas dos listas en tu último `for`

```
for k in range(1, n + 1):
    oracion = "Actividad: {} OT: {}".format(lista_dato_caso[k], lista_fila_ot[k])
    print(oracion)
```

**Conclusión:** Si necesitas generar o imprimir varios valores, por lo general hay una lista, diccionario o tupla involucrada en hacerlo

Por lo que, si el siguiente paso es obtener una lista de oraciones entonces tendrás que crear otra lista y utilizar `append()` dentro de tu último `for`

Comment: Gracias! la última línea la escribí así:
for k in range(n):
    print(k)
    oracion = "Actividad:{} OT: {}".format(lista_caso_dato[k], lista_fila_ot[k])

Ya que al dejar for k in range(1, n + 1):  deja fuera de rango la lista creada
Ahora el código muestra lo que solicito

Comment: @PatrickFuentes, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas